# Tool for finding non-virtual destructors

Tags: c++, linux

Anyone know of a tool that can find non-virtual destructors of polymorphic base classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiling with `g++ -Wall` will give a warning about that. Or `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` if you just want that warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -Wall
```

will print messages like

```
class x has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [cpplint](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/) from google will check this and other C++ style things. If you just want to check virtual destructors `cpplint --filter=-,+runtime/virtual` will limit the reported problems to just those.